# Sharepoint 2007 Custom List requirement

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to create custom column in SharePoint List Like : It should be Edited by Only authorized person or group . There are 5 columns in the Custom List.

User 1 Will insert only first Three column of list ,first 3 column having one column system Date : Date When User1 insert the starting 3 details .

User 2 will edit the details of User One and remaining Column consisting of Remark and Revised Date : Revised date is the Date when User 2 updated the Details .

how can Implement this in SharePoint 2007 .

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like such:
Create a default content type that only has the 3 columns you need.  Make this the default content type.  Give the group Add only permissions.

The second content type would have the other fields including the fields from the first content type.  Group 2, with edit permissions, can edit the item, switch the content type and fill out the remaining information.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't support field level security OOTB. So you have to use some third party solution (there are some as I know) or implement your own custom solution. One way to do the latter is to create custom list item editing forms for your list. You can create a custom aspx page with any logic and configure a content type with this form - [here](http://aarebrot.net/blog/2011/08/creating-custom-content-type-forms-using-aspx-pages-in-sharepoint-2007/)'s an example. Then you can simply use your content type in your custom list. It's quite easy to do but feel free to ask if you need more info. And you're need to disable "data sheet view" in your list because it provides the way to edit data without using list item forms.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a custom Workflow. Each steps of the workflows will have its own fields set in a custom task assigned to the correct user. The sharepoint item itself won't be updated by the users, but by the worklow.

Just be careful, it can quiclky be complicated depending on your needs.